# How to filter an object in a Sparql query (nested query)?

Tags: sparql

I am trying to make a SPARQL query, but it doesn't seem to be operating as expected. How can I select all ?io that has a metadata with type of http://www.test/#Entity ?

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT ?uuid ?meta WHERE { 
    ?io a <http://www.test.com/rig#InfObject> . 
    ?io <http://www.test.com/rig#uniqueID> ?uuid . 
    ?io <http://www.test.com/rig#metadata> ?meta . 
    { 
        SELECT ?meta WHERE { 
            ?meta a <http://www.test/#Entity> . 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: there is no need for a subquery, just use the triple pattern in the outer query.. If it doesn't work, your query simply does not match the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to perform a new select. Just add the information

```
SELECT ?uuid ?meta
WHERE
  { 
    ?io   a                             <http://example/rig#InfObject> .
    ?io   <http://example/rig#uniqueID> ?uuid                          .
    ?io   <http://example/rig#metadata> ?meta                          .
    ?meta a                             <http://example/#Entity>       .
  }
```